# Power BI - Line Chart with changing color for trend

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart

Just wondering if it's possible to create a chart like below.

[image: Line chart with changing trend color]

I have created the following measures in DAX:

```
1. [Total Sales]

2. [PM Sale] = 
CALCULATE([TotalSales], PARALLELPERIOD('Date'[Date], -1, MONTH)) // Previous month Sales

3. [Indicator] = IF([TotalSales] - [PM Sale] >=0, 1, 0)

4. [IndicatorText] = IF([TotalSales] - [PM Sale] >=0, "UP", "DOWN")
```

I thought adding the [Indicator] or [IndicatorText] to "Legend" property of line chart would be possible and then be able to change the color, but it is not.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Shiv

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly what you are requesting, but a waterfall chart works pretty well here.

Create a measure to be the difference from the last month and use that for the waterfall chart's y-axis with the date in the category section.

```
Diff = [Total Sales] - CALCULATE([Total Sales], PARALLELPERIOD('Date'[Date], -1, MONTH))
```

[image: Waterfall Chart]

You can also use a regular bar chart with two series:

```
Up   = IF([Diff] >= 0, [Total Sales], BLANK())
Down = IF([Diff] <  0, [Total Sales], BLANK())
```

[image: Combo Bar Chart]

---

If you convert this to a line chart, it would look like this (you need to set the x-axis to categorical instead of continuous):

[image: Disconnected Line Chart]

It's possible to tweak the measures a bit by looking at the next month in addition to the previous month and get what you want for this particular case, but it won't work correctly in general:

[image: Line Chart]

You can't tell from the image, but the first red line segment is covering a green line segment. If red and green segments alternate, then this methodology breaks down.

---

Here are the adjusted measured for the chart above:

```
Forward = IF(ISBLANK(PARALLELPERIOD('Date'[Date] , 1, MONTH)),
             BLANK(),
             CALCULATE([Total Sales]),
                 PARALLELPERIOD('Date'[Date], 1, MONTH))
             - [Total Sales])

Up   = IF([Diff] >= 0 || [Forward] >= 0, [Total Sales], BLANK())
Down = IF([Diff] <  0 || [Forward] <  0, [Total Sales], BLANK())
```

Comment: Can you not use that measure in the Legend property for the line chart?

Comment: You can, but it won't give you quite what you want.

Comment: I see. I agree your solution should work fine for OP, I was just curious since I don't have any test data handy I could use to try this way with a line chart.

Comment: Thank you @AlexisOlson. Here's another solution from Power BI Community https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Line-Chart-With-States-or-Change-color-with-direction-of-trend/m-p/475027/highlight/true#M220898